# Implementing Request Response in Apache Kafka java

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, request-response

Please find the use case we need to implement.

First, we need to invoke a Kafka producer a message as a rest service, they will process and give back the response in another topic.

For us, It is a request-reply topic we need to reply back for the same request the response, using **replykafka** template is working fine, but we can set **co-relation id** in the header.

As a topic message metadata there are sending in attributes, is there any way to map the co-relation id with request topic message and reply topic message.

Explain to you better.

One microservice expects the payload as given below with **correlationId** in payload.

```
{
  "operationDate": "2020-09-16T11:58:25",
  "correlationId": "-5544538377183901824042719876882142227",
  "birthDate": "2013-12-12",
  "firstNameEn": "boby",
  "firstNameAr": "الشيخ",
}
```

The microservice will process the payload and will give a response in another topic as.

```
{
  "correlationId": -5544538377183901824042719876882142227,
  "consumerId": null,
  "userid": 123456,
  "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
  "errors": null
}
```

Now as this we need to implement using spring ReplyingKafkaTemplate.

As ReplyingKafkaTemplate will work with correlationId in the header only

Comment: Sorry, not clear what is an idea to carry a correlation id over in the request `ProducerRecord`? You can't use headers for that? Why?

Comment: See my answer; use a `correlationIdStrategy` `Function`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan You are right, we should or can use in the header, but the microservice we are calling is only allowing in payload rather than the header. That is the problem we need to hook the same co-relation id in the payload also .

Comment: @GaryRussell we need a way so that we could append in payload and same they will process the message in topic and put in another kafka topic with same co-relation id

Comment: Much clearer. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you want to include the topic(s) in the correlation id, see

```java
/**
 * Set a function to be called to establish a unique correlation key for each request
 * record.
 * @param correlationStrategy the function.
 * @since 2.3
 */
public void setCorrelationIdStrategy(Function<ProducerRecord<K, V>, CorrelationKey> correlationStrategy) {
```

You can create your own correlation id, based on the `ProducerRecord` (which has the `topic()`).

You just need to make sure it is unique. If you manually set the `KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC`, it will be visible to the strategy.

**EDIT**

With the correlation id in the payload, use `setCorrelationIdStrategy` to extract the correlationId from the payload and add a `RecordInterceptor` to do the same on the reply side.

Comment: I thought his point that they can't rely on this `headers.add(new RecordHeader(this.correlationHeaderName, correlationId.getCorrelationId()));`. Sounds like the other part can't read Kafka headers...

Comment: I agree; the question is not clear; let's wait for clarification :)

Comment: Hi, the question was using spring replaykafka default the Kafka template will add correlationId in header of the message and if the same correlationId came in replaycontainer, it will map for the same request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint.

I have done as overriding the payload with Kafka header correlationId.

```
@Override
    protected ListenableFuture<SendResult> doSend(ProducerRecord producerRecord) {
        if(producerRecord.value()!=null){
           // i have appeneded the header correlationId in th payload
        }
        return super.doSend(producerRecord);
    }
```

And in Replay onMessage ,i have populated the response payload correlationId to the header.

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<K, R>> data) {
        data.forEach(
            krConsumerRecord -> //update each record header
        );
        super.onMessage(data);
    }
```

In this way was successfully integrated request-response semantics with correlationId in the request and response payload.